# How is class of composition of two quadratic fields is related class numbers of quadratic field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let  $K_1=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_1})$ ,  $K_2=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_2})$ and  $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_1},\sqrt{d_2})$.Suppose $h_1,h_2,h$ be class number of $K_1,K_2,K$ respectively.

(i) Can we express $h$ in terms of $h_1,h_2$?

(ii) Knowing the divisibility properties  of  $h_1,h_2$, I want help with   concluding about the divisibility of $h_1,h_2.$

Comment: You did not define $d$ in terms of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Also as is written, $K_1=K_2$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you mean $K_1=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_1})$.

1) If by $K$ you mean $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_1d_2})$, then there is no simple relation
between $h$ and $h_1$ and $h_2$.

2) If by $K$ you mean the quartic biquadratic field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_1},\sqrt{d_2})$, a theorem of Herglotz says that $h=h_1h_2h_3/2^j$, where
$h_3$ is the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d_1d_2})$ and $j=0,1,2$ which can
be computed in terms of the units of $K$.

Comment: Sorry I meant K to be the composition K_1 and K_2. Can you  please provide some reference for theorem of Herglotz

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01482079